# Apache 2: calling 'a2ensite' from a bash script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, apache2

I am currently writing an admin page for my webserver, to make it easier on myself to create new apache domains from my browser. Everything is pretty much working as I want it to, except for one thing.

To elaborate: I have a cron job on my server running a bash script as root that checks a file containing a list of domain names that I want to be created. If the file contains a domain name, it automatically creates a new virtual host for this domain, edits my hosts file, and restarts the server. This all works perfectly, however what I would like for the script to do, is that it activates the domain that it automatically creates before it restarts the server. I tried doing this using apache 2's `a2ensite` command, however the script returns an error saying the command is not found.

Is there a way to call this command from a bash script, or is there an alternative to this command that I can call?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ which a2ensite
/usr/sbin/a2ensite
```

Usually, cron has a quite restrictive $PATH, not including `/usr/sbin` or `/sbin`, which are system binaries (for use by root). It's always a good idea to use fully qualified path names. So either call `/usr/bin/a2ensite` in your script, or define a variable:

```
A2ENSITE=/usr/sbin/a2ensite
...
${A2ENSITE} new-domain.com
```

Comment: the same can be done in the bashrc to add a shortcut for the command right. Ex: alias a2ensite /usr/sbin/a2ensite